# Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'io'

Tags: python-3.x, appium

I am trying to run my tests suite but getting this import error; please help me fix it.

```
from io import path
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'io' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/io.py)
```

Comment: Where is that error from? The `io` module indeed doesn't have a `path` member.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. The problem was that the path was pointing to an empty folder. Thanks!